# Fonts in this text

Tags: fonts

I want to know what the fonts are in this pdf. Which package to use?
[image]

Comment: It's Palatino: `\usepackage{mathpazo}`

Comment: Or use `xetex` or `luatex` engines (possibly with the `fontspec` package) which let you work with any system font without font-specific packages.

Comment: Use the pdffonts command on linux to find out what fonts are in a document.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The font seems to be Palatino (in one of its many incarnations). On TeX distributions it's available with

```
\usepackage{mathpazo}
```

that also has a dedicated math font based on Palatino.

[image]

A different realization is with TeX Gyre Pagella

```
\usepackage{tgpagella}
```

[image]

---

With XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX one can use the OpenType version of the latter font:

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella}
```

or

```
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella}
\setmathfont{TG Pagella Math}
```

if you want to use also the companion math font.